# could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor:

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, format

I have this piece of code:

```
public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    OffsetDateTime.parse(startTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DateFormat.DATE_PATTERN)
```

But I have this error when parsing:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2019-07-10 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: For an `OffSetDateTime`, I think you need the offset. This is more like a `LocalDate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)

> A date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 Europe/Paris.

[LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

> A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03.

Since your string just represents simple date, so use `LocalDate`

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(startTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that these parse methods need the offset string part (+/-hh:mm), if you want to use `OffsetDateTime` you need to add that part, here some examples:

```
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-10-02T20:15:30+01:00",
                DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

If you just want that format, "yyyy-mm-dd" you just need to go with traditional `LocalDate.parse`